# How can I do this more readable?

Tags: php, laravel

I have to make permissions on seeder. Right now I have something like this:

```
$adminPermissions = collect([
    $adminPermissions = collect([
        'permission_read',
        'permission_list',
        'permission_create',
        'permission_edit',
        'permission_delete',
        'role_read',
        'role_list',
        'role_create',
        'role_edit',
        'role_delete',
    ])->map(function ($name) {
        return Permission::create([
            'name' => $name
        ]);
    });

    ])->map(function ($name) {
        return Permission::create([
            'name' => $name
        ]);
    });
```

But I want to make something like this:

```
    $rolePermissions = [
        'role_read',
        'role_list',
        'role_create',
        'role_edit',
        'role_delete',
    ];

    $permissionsForPermissions = [
        'permission_read',
        'permission_list',
        'permission_create',
        'permission_edit',
        'permission_delete',
    ];

    $adminPermissions = collect([
      $PermissionsForPermissions, 
      $rolePermissions
    ])->map(function ($name) {
        return Permission::create([
            'name' => $name
        ]);
    });
```

I know that this will not work because collect is waiting only for one array but I am asking if it's possible to do something like this because the first example is ugly.

Comment: why is the first one ugly? o.O

Comment: and as the code is all-working, this is actually off-topic and I believe best suited to the codereview SE - though I may be wrong

Comment: Doesn't Gate be used to divide permissions?

Comment: Okay, sorry for this question I found out how to do this.

Comment: @Marius Hey, no need to be sorry. I think your question is fine, you did provide a [mcve] and you explained what you wanted to achieve. Keep up the good work! I'm glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php), to merge your permission's arrays into one. So it will be something like:

```php
$adminPermissions = collect(
      array_merge(
          $permissionsForPermissions, 
          $rolePermissions
      )
    )->map(function ($name) {
        return Permission::create([
            'name' => $name
        ]);
    });
```

P.S. I am still not sure this is "more readable", but tastes differs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this. I used it like this way

```
$permission = array(
        array('name' => 'user_view'),
        array('name' => 'user_create'),
        array('name' => 'user_edit'),
        array('name' => 'user_delete'),
        array('name' => 'project_view'),
        array('name' => 'project_create'),
        array('name' => 'project_edit'),
        array('name' => 'project_delete'),
        array('name' => 'team_view'),
        array('name' => 'team_create'),
        array('name' => 'team_edit'),
        array('name' => 'team_delete')
        );
       Permission::insert($permission);
```